# Qt qsqlquery. Is exec() sync or async?

Tags: qt, firebird

I'm using firebird embedded db with Qt provider.
For working with db I use qsqlquery::exec() function.
Is this function sync or async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QSqlQuery::exec()` is blocking (synchronous) but not atomic, the OS can interrupt the thread and run another thread inbetween.

Note that you shouldn't share a single database connection across threads anyway, so there shouldn't be problems.

Comment: Thanks you.
Yeah, I'm using db across 2 thread (gui and working thread) and I've strange errors from firebird:
"deadlock - deadlock - update conflicts with concurrent update - concurrent transaction number is 1323."
I've created a new connection in a working thread (gui connection is still active but isn't using) and at the same moment "deadlock .." error is appeared. What is the problem? Can you help?

Comment: Also:Should I call qsqlquery::finish() function for all queries or not (for local variables or class members that is frequently used) ?

Comment: Can u mark and close this question, then open new one and attach some part of code, please?